# Get titlebar text size WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get the (text size or height) of the titlebar.
I tried to use `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION)` but it returns the height of the titlebar not the text size.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) passing `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS`. This will populate a [`NONCLIENTMETRICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff729175.aspx) structure. Within that structure is `lfCaptionFont` which contains the information you desire.

Comment: NONCLIENTMETRICS m; 
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS,NULL,&m,NULL);
but I get empty struct ?
I'm using WS_POPUP window

Comment: You failed to do what the documentation said. *The pvParam parameter must point to a NONCLIENTMETRICS structure that receives the information. Set the cbSize member of this structure and the uiParam parameter to sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS).* It is critical that you read documentation very carefully. Note also that you did not check the return value for errors. Again, you must always do that.