# Windows API nonclientmetrics for individual window

Tags: windows, winapi, metrics, titlebar, caption

I direly need to have access to the caption font of a window with individual skin/style in Win7 and Win8. So using Windows APIs standard NONCLIENTMETRIC and SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS getter don't work at all, as they return general defaults (see here [Get titlebar text size WINAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921400/get-titlebar-text-size-winapi/27921444#27921444) for instance)

Any idea how I can access the non client metrics & fonts (best as LOGFONT type) in this case? I scrawled stackoverflow and searched with search machines and MSDN sites without success yet...

Comment: No reason for you to expect to obtain this information. If the app paints the NC area itself, then it doesn't need to tell anybody which font it used.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for thy answer. Suppose, however, the app uses the standard Windows API for setting NC fonts etc. Is there any API function at all for getting the metrics, potentially returning nullptr if it cannot handle the information or if there is none?

Comment: What is this standard API?

Comment: Well, the windows API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920508(vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which function is the app calling that is "setting the NC fonts etc."? Can we first be clear on the question you are asking.

Comment: Sure: Such as CreatePointFont, CreatePointFontIndirect and SetFont (afaik all declared in afxwin.h).

Comment: Those are not Win32 APi functions. That's MFC. I'm not sure that you are really quite clear on how this all works. Maybe we should go right back to the beginning. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? Let's start there instead of with your proposed solution, which I suspect is not the right solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75910/discussion-between-gilgamash-and-david-heffernan).